# logj4 message to json

Tags: java, json, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a message lets say `delay=1, name=Ash` that I want to log using `log4j2`. Every line of my log file I want it to be in json format like that

```
{"@timestamp": 1234, "delay"=1, "name"="Ash"}
```

The `@timestamp` field is the timestamp produced by the logger whereas the `delay` and `name` fields are fields of the message.

Is there a way to do that? By using the `JsonLayout` I know that I can have every logged output in json format but still I haven't found a way to manipulate the log message so that I can place different parts of it in different fields.

Comment: AFAIK you can only have the complete message as one json field.

Comment: Ideally I want to avoid that, but to know that there is no way is also helpful

Comment: Timestamp is a part of the meta information of the message itself, you actually want to 'move your message to the meta data'. Have you tried MDC? -> If you use PatternLayout, you can put e.g. the current user in the context and reuse it in your message. If that won't work an no one comes up with a solution, I'd suggest to implement your own JsonLayout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using log4j2 JSONLayout.

- First you have to specify jsonlayout

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JSONLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" properties="true"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here if you set compact = false, json will be in print in prity format

- Second you can `ThreadContext` to put value as key value pair.

Example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ThreadContext.clearAll();
    ThreadContext.put("delay", String.valueOf(i));
    ThreadContext.put("name", "Ash " + i);
    LOGGER.info("Testing ", "k1", "v1", "k2", "v2");
}
```

Here `ThreadContext` keep all the key value pair until you clear.

Output :

```
{"timeMillis":1491819918389,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ashraful.ilpexp.LogTest","message":"Testing ","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"delay":"0","name":"Ash 0"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
{"timeMillis":1491819918504,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ashraful.ilpexp.LogTest","message":"Testing ","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"delay":"1","name":"Ash 1"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
{"timeMillis":1491819918504,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ashraful.ilpexp.LogTest","message":"Testing ","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"delay":"2","name":"Ash 2"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
{"timeMillis":1491819918505,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ashraful.ilpexp.LogTest","message":"Testing ","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"delay":"3","name":"Ash 3"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
{"timeMillis":1491819918505,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ashraful.ilpexp.LogTest","message":"Testing ","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"delay":"4","name":"Ash 4"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern='{"@timestamp": %d{UNIX_MILLIS}, "delay"=%X{delay}, "name"="%X{name}"}%n'/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void logMsg(long delay, String name) {
    ThreadContext.put("delay", delay + "");
    ThreadContext.put("name", name);
    logger.info("");
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{"@timestamp": 1491821218548, "delay"=1, "name"="hello"}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In fact, I prefer to build the log message string directly in the code.

e.g.

```
public static void logMsg(long delay, String name) {
  String s = String.format("{\"@timestamp\":%s, \"delay\"=%s, \"name\"=\"%s\"}", System.currentTimeMillis(), delay, name);
  logger.info(s);
}
```

Note: change the log4j2.xml pattern layout to

```
<PatternLayout pattern='%msg%n'/>
```

Comment: your second example does not work with your first config, which in this case should look like `patern=%m%n` I guess.

Comment: Yes, I just want to keep my answer as simple as possible.